# php, count characters and deleted what is more than 140 characters

Tags: php, count, trim

I need a PHP function that will count the number of characters of a phrase. If the phrase is longer than "140" character then this function should delete all the other character and add three points at then end of the phrase.
So for example we have.

```
$message= "I am what I am and you are what you are etc etc etc etc"
```

IF this is longer than 140 characters, then

```
$message= "I am what I am and you are what you are..."
```

Is this possible? How?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(strlen($str) > 140){
   $str =  substr($str, 0, 140).'...';
}
```

Comment: Just simple and perfect. Thanks

Comment: If you want the string to be 140 characters with the `...`, you will need `$str = substr($str, 0, 137) . '...';`

Comment: You don't even need the `if` statement.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be "word sensitive" (i.e. not break in the middle of the word), you can use [`wordwrap()`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Comment: Also note that you can use wordwrap to not be word-sensitive by giving `true` as the fourth parameter ($cut) :)

Answer (score 5):

This variant will work correct with necessary charset (e.g. utf-8), and will try to cut by space, to not break words:

```
$charset = 'utf-8';
$len = iconv_strlen($str, $charset);
$max_len = 140;
$max_cut_len = 10;
if ($len > $max_len)
{
    $str = iconv_substr($str, 0, $max_len, $charset);
    $prev_space_pos = iconv_strrpos($str, ' ', $charset);
    if (($max_len-$prev_space_pos) < $max_cut_len) $str = iconv_substr($str, 0, $prev_space_pos, $charset);
    $str .= '...';
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning charset/utf-8, which all the other answers don't consider. didn't test your code, though.

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
/**
 * trim up to 140 characters
 * @param string $str the string to shorten
 * @param int $length (optional) the max string length to return
 * @return string the shortened string
 */
function shorten($str, $length = 140) {
    if (strlen($str) > $length) {
        return substr($str, 0, $length).'...';
    }
    return $str;
}

/**
 * trim till last space before 140 characters
 * @param string $str the string to shorten
 * @param int $length (optional) the max string length to return
 * @return string the shortened string
 */
function smartShorten($str, $length = 140) {
    if (strlen($str) > $length) {
        if (false === ($pos = strrpos($str, ' ', $length))) { // no space found; cut till $length
            return substr($str, 0, $length).'...';
        }
        return substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ' ', $length)).'...';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: A closing ')' bracket is missing in ' if ' statement at
if (false === ($pos = strrpos($str, ' ', $length)))

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that i use quite often

```
function shorten($str,$l = 30){
    return (strlen($str) > $l)? substr($str,0,$l)."...": $str;
}
```

you can change the default length to anything you want