# Cutting a string with accents

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

Hello,

I'm developing a site in French and I created a function that cuts string after X number of characters.  It works great, but when the last character has an accent, it has the (?) instead of the character.

Here is my function

```
function neat_trim3($str, $n, $delim='...') {
    $len = strlen($str);
    if ($len > $n) {
        $tocut = $len-$n;
        $output = substr($str,0,-$tocut);
        return $len.' - '.$output.$delim;
    }
    else {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Example

```
$str = "C'est une soirée privé ce soir";
echo eat_trim3($str, 15 , '...' );   
// GIVES ME             C'est une soir�...
```

The rest of the page echos the page perfectly, I can even echo the same string without the cut and it works great.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001690/php-count-characters-and-deleted-what-is-more-than-140-characters/6001742#6001742

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) functions. It doesn't work because you are using UTF-8, which has multi-byte characters and you cut the in the middle.

Comment: This is perfect. You made my life better. Thanks